# Issues with repositories - some are missing

Tags: repositories

I installed Elementary OS yesterday and am trying to get it to work but have encountered several problems. First off, I'm unable to find all the repositories available usually through ubuntu's standard repository list. For example when trying to search for valve's "Steam" it is missing form the list:

```
sl/focal 5.02-1 amd64
Correct you if you type `sl' by mistake

steam-devices/focal 1:1.0.0.61-2ubuntu3 all
Device support for Steam-related hardware
```

It should after all be between those two points there. It is NOT one of my installed repositories either.

Is this a common issue? I'm on the latest elementary os version Jolnir.

How would I go about getting the correct repositories up?
installed:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu focal main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list.save:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu focal main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu focal main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list.save:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu focal main 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list.save:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/philip_scott-ubuntu-pantheon-tweaks-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/pantheon-tweaks/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/philip_scott-ubuntu-pantheon-tweaks-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/pantheon-tweaks/ubuntu focal main
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sudo apt update, if you find the update not fixing the problem then you need to get them else where and install